# Add email alert when button clicked

Tags: email, alert

This is the code for the submit button

```
 <div class="submit_btn_input"><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit"  /></div>
```

What do I need to add to this to send an email when it is clicked?

Comment: You have to write a PHP script which is sending a email and call it on buttonclick.

Comment: You cannot send emails from HTML or javascript. What server side programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the mail() function in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Why did you assume that the OP is using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Without PHP try to put it into `<form action="mailto:myforms@mydomain.com"></form>`.

[Check here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/email-form-mailto.html)